# Hibernate interprets NULL timestamp as current date/time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a MySQL database table with a column called expirationDate, which is defined as a timestamp that defaults to NULL. I have a method that pulls all records from the table that match various criteria, then prints the column values for each record as part of a debugging routine.

When viewing the records returned, I noticed that records that have a NULL expirationDate in the DB were being returned to my program with the expirationDate set to the current date/time.

Is this normal behavior? If so, is it configurable (I'd like the value to remain NULL)?

I am using Hibernate 3.x libraries.

Comment: Please post your criteria and model mapping code. This way it would be much easier to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Hibernate turning `null` values into current timestamps, it's MySQL. At least that's the most probable reason. The behaviour of the `TIMESTAMP` column depends on multiple parameters:

- Whether it's the first `TIMESTAMP` column in table (different defaults apply)
- The table engine (MyISAM or InnoDB)
- The configuration ([MAXDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_maxdb) setting)
- Your MySQL version

Of course the behaviour is [sufficiently defined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html), also in regard to [`TIMESTAMP` and `NULL` values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html#idm140599559624304), yet it remains confusing. I stopped using many MySQL automagical features, e. g. because there will be other people who have to deal with the code and tables later.

You should check the values in your table and the output of `CREATE TABLE` with the MySQL command line client or PMA. Do you have `null` values in your tables?

If you had your tables created by Hibernate 3, the generated DDL statements might also be wrong (see [this post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/26575?_sscc=t)).